I need help to identify this similar lego freestyle
I'm dying trying to find where this lego came from. Maybe it's from 80s.
Some pieces have a tiny number inside. They are made of a resistant plastic.





The studs remind me of LINO bricks. The corners appear to be rounded somewhat though (possibly through use), and the underside looks more modern, so possibly a later evolution ? The specialty pieces (windows, doors, triangular bricks) don't look familiar.
